# Putting imageview on navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add image to right side of navigation bar. But I can't drag image view to navigation bar. I can only drag a button.

[image]

How can I do this ? I want same thing with whatsapp profile image. You know they have circle profile picture on right side of navigation bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drag a UIView and drop it on the navigation bar first. Then drag a UIImageView into the view.

That should give you what you are looking for.

Set the image view height and width using constraints. You have to set the width and height of the containing view in the size inspector.

Answer (score 9):

```
**This will Display the image on right side on navigation bar**
```

[image]

```
 func viewDidLoad(){
        let containView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
                let imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
                imageview.image = UIImage(named: "photo.jpg")
                imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
                imageview.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true
                containView.addSubview(imageview)
                let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about storyboards. But from code you can create `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view.

```
        let customView = UIImageView()
        let customViewItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customViewItem
```

From storyboard:

Just drag `UIBarButtonItem` into your controller navigation bar. In element menu(Attribute inspector) select identifier: `Custom` and Image: the image you want.

Comment: How this code knows to where to place ?  I mean why this code is placing a image to right not left ?

Comment: It is only an example how to create it.